# htaccess rewrite rule disregard directory

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, rules

I am new to using htaccess and rewite rules.
I need to write a rewrite rule which "disregards" any directory starting with a certain prefix.

For example, any directory starting with `_prefix_`should be disregarded so that

```
http://www.myserver.com/mydir/_prefix_12n3n4n/subdir/file
```

should be redirected to
    `http://www.myserver.com/mydir/subdir/file`

Can anyone tell me how this would be done?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out...
    `RewriteRule "(.*)([^\/]*)(_prefix_[^\/]*[\/])" "$1$4"`

seems to work